# How to test server speed with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to test the speed of my servers, and compare it with third parties' servers including Facebook, Tumblr and Google. I need to build a report with at least 100's of requests and I decided to do this with Python.

The idea is that I upload an image to Facebook, then re-download it (as Facebook modifies the image I upload) and upload it to the other third party servers as well as my own. I request the file x times for each server, and Python will print the time the request took each time.

Here is my script:

```
from time import time
from urllib import urlopen

# vars
url = raw_input("Please enter the URL you want to test: ")

for i in range(0,100):
    start_time = time()
    pic = urlopen(url)

    if pic.getcode() == 200:
        delta_time = time() - start_time
        print "%d" % (delta_time * 100)
    else:
        print "error"
print "%d requests made. File size: %d B" % (i, len(pic.read()))
```

I'm not great at Python so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.

**Is this the best way to do this?**

Comment: If the code works the way it should, then, strictly speaking, the question is a little off-topic here; there's a site called [codereview.se] where you can post working code for review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [Lev Levitsky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148092/how-to-test-server-speed-with-python#comment16253356_12148092), this question actually belongs over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). The code I originally posted as intended, all I'm looking for is guidance on how to improve it.

[Here is this question on Code Review.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15113/rapidly-requesting-a-file-from-a-server)

Answer (score 1):

There are scores of [HTTP performance testing tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=http+performance+testing+tools) available. I would suggest you try one of those before creating your own.

Comment: Such as 'ab' (Apache Benchmarking tool): http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html

Comment: Can I use this to test third party servers? I need to compare my download times to that of Facebook, Tumblr, Google, etc

Comment: If you go and hammer someone else's server, they might consider it a DoS attack and blacklist you, or take legal action. Besides, your server will never be faster than your internet connection. And I suspect Google and Facebook can afford a bigger "pipe" than most of us.